Cannot use apt-get at all after installing python libraries
I was working on a tutorial of how to build a rest api with python, using uvicorn. When i installed "pyrebase" and tried runing uvicorn, it reported problems importing the module "deque" from "collections". I tried changing some variable names (in the document there were comments about changes asi "_colections_abc" instead of "colecions.abc" and so. Yes, big mistake... Still didnt solve anything.
Now when i try to use apt or apt-get to install, remove, purge or anything, i get a long response along like :
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/email/feedparser.py", line 28, in <module>
    from collections import deque
ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

Ive tried many options, but most involve using apt or apt-get which i cant... Any suggestions?

Where did you change collections.abc to _collections_abc?

Some files including "contextlib.py" and "init"

Where are those files?

/usr/lib/python3.10/_collections_abc.py and /usr/lib/python3.10/collections/init.py
When i go to "collections_abc" which is the file that should have the "deque" class, there is nothing... https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/_collections_abc.py

Okay. No wonder something that was in those files cannot be found anymore. You should undo your changes.

I tried undoing the changes, but it still continues to call those errors. And the problem isnt the api anymore, is the fact that i cannot use apt at all

I guess that's because apt is trying to use your system installation of Python, which you modified.

apt is a python script - so don't change original Python.

maybe you could download python as file .deb and use command dpgk -i your_package.deb to install this package (without using apt)

thanks for the answer. i tried doing the installation through wget and tar... but i got this
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151
distutils: /usr/local/include/python3.10/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /home/fito/Python-3.10.0/Include/UNKNOWN
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = '/'
prefix = None
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/tmps9b77c8w/pip-21.2.3-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main

in fact the error is longer, but that was the first few lines
